# Special Character in PHP variable?

Tags: php

I want to insert a phone number to a database.

My problem now is, how to add a `+` character to the variable and save it to the database?

This is my form :

```
<form action="proccess.php" method="POST">
<input type="number" name="number">
<button type="submit">Send!</button>
```

Dnd this is `process.php`:

```
<?php
$phone = $_POST['number'];
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phonenumber VALUES('$phone')");
?>
```

So I want to insert the data to be `+111111111` for example.

Comment: `$phone = '+' . $phone`;

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but that code is wide open for attacks! Inserting `+` in the database shouldn't be an issue, unless you've created a field with int type etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$phone = "+" . $_POST['number'];
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phonenumber VALUES('$phone')");
?>
```

Additionally, consider using the newer `mysqli_`-functions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PDO.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

$phone = '+'.$_POST['number'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO phonenumber (phone) VALUES (:phone)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':phone'=>$phone));
```